# Uncheck a radio button on a bundle product page

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, checkbox

Thought this would be simple however having some difficulty. I want to uncheck a radio button, and even checkboxes, however, have achieved checkboxes with just simulated clicks. The below I have tried:

```
$( "#x" ).prop( "checked", false );
$( "#x" ).attr('checked', false);
$( "#x" ).removeAttr('checked');
```

I have also tried javascript checked = false and other methods, I also noticed the `jQuery/UI` `.checkboxradio('refresh')` method however could not get this to fire. Used the `jQuery/UI` as a whole as could not find the specific module however function did not seem available.

Anyone got a nice solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to check some radio buttons using the console as per the screenshot below. However, within a group, one radio seems to remain checked. In other words, to uncheck one radio, I had to check a radio from the same group

[image]

Apologies I have the questions not right, hopefully this was what you meant

Comment: Thanks for having a go trickier than it sounds this one. Kinda want to reset the whole form so uncheck all radio selections with javascript.

Comment: my answer is telling you html wise (nothing to do with Magento), a radio group cannot have all its options deselected. It did come to my mind to add an option that is selected by default and hide it with jquery?